# Live Offers - Coupon -

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does any one know how to use the "Live Offers" fonctionality to export a coupon code type : Codabar ?

I have displayed in Email a coupon Code type : Plain Text but when i choose "Codabar" type, it doesn't generate a codabar.

If you have a website or other documentation except for [www.help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/live_offers/](http://www.help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/live_offers/)

Thank you